# Angular Date Picker Empty Value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Here is my code. I have a dialog that displays a date picker. The date picker always opens up with a date but, I want the date picker to be empty if `IsPrimerExists` value is false. How can I do this?

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="!productionValue1">
    <mat-label>{{'İmalat Tarihi(' + Country1 +' '+Market1+')'}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="filterWeekend" [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="countryDate1"
        name="countryDate1">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

IProductionOrder Interface:

```
IsPrimerExists?: boolean;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the value to `null` or `undefined` if `IsPrimerExists` is `false`. So wherever you have access to `IsPrimerExists` assign the value to `countryDate1`. Something like...

```
this.countryDate1 = this.IsPrimerExist ? new Date() : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The picker is bound to  `[(ngModel)]="countryDate1"`, so if you set countryDate1 to null then it will open without date I guess